# Removing C++ template arguments from a C++ function name

Tags: python

I'm working on some code that deals with mangled C++ function names. I'm displaying these to the user, so to help with readability of some of the really long C++ template class/function names, I'm removing some of the template arguments based on how deeply nested the template argument is.

The code below works fine, but it seems fairly clunky. It feels like I'm "writing C in any language". I'm wondering if I can improve it, shorten it, and make it more pythonic.

```
def removeTemplateArguments(str, depthToRemove):
    """ Remove template arguments deeper than depthToRemove
        so removeTemplateArguments("foo<int>()", 1) gives foo<>()
           removeTemplateArguments("foo< bar<int> >()", 1) gives foo< >()
           removeTemplateArguments("foo< bar<int> >()", 2) gives foo< bar<> >()"""
    if depthToRemove <= 0:
        return str
    currDepth = 0
    res = ""
    for c in str:
        if currDepth < depthToRemove:
            res += c
        if c == "<":
            currDepth += 1
        elif c == ">":
            currDepth -= 1
            if currDepth < depthToRemove:
                res += ">"
    return res
```

Comment: This is a C++ comment rather than a Python answer, but, please be aware that attempting to parse C++ template names with hand-written code places you in a state of sin just as much as if you were [considering arithmetical methods of producing random digits](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/John_von_Neumann). Consider how your code will handle `bool_< 1<2 >` or  `bool_< (1>2) >` or `bool_< 1>= 2 >` (assuming `template<bool X> using bool_ = std::integral_constant<bool,X>` of course), and then consider whether you are *really* helping your users with this code.

Answer (score 5):

For that kind of parsing [`itertools.groupby`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) is the right tool.

With `groupby`, as I used it down below, every group is either: `<`,`>` or an actual piece of code (like `foo`). So the only thing left to do is to increment/decrement the depth level and decide if the group should be appended or not to the final result list.

```
from itertools import groupby

def remove_arguments(template, depth):
    res = []
    curr_depth = 0
    for k,g in groupby(template, lambda x: x in ['<', '>']):
        text = ''.join(g)    # rebuild the group as a string
        if text == '<':
            curr_depth += 1

        # it's important to put this part in the middle
        if curr_depth < depth:
            res.append(text)
        elif k and curr_depth == depth:   # add the inner <>
            res.append(text)

        if text == '>':
            curr_depth -= 1

    return ''.join(res)   # rebuild the complete string
```

It's important to put the depth-level check in between the increment and decrement part, because it has to be decided if the `<`/`>` are *in* or *out* the current depth level.

Output examples:

```
>>> remove_arguments('foo<int>()', 1)
foo<>()
>>> remove_arguments('foo< bar<int> >()', 1)
foo<>()
>>> remove_arguments('foo< bar<int> >()', 2)
foo< bar<> >()
>>> remove_arguments('foo< bar >()', 2)
foo< bar >()
```

Also, a couple of quick style notes:

- Don't use `str` as variable name or you'll shadow the builitin [`str`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functions.html#str).
- Don't use `CamelCase` for functions/variable names (look at [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)).

---

Inspired by *lvc* comment, I've grouped here possible lambdas/functions to be used in `groupby`:

```
groupby(template, lambda x: x in ['<', '>'])    # most obvious one
groupby(template, lambda x: x in '<>')   # equivalent to the one above
groupby(template, '<>'.__contains__)    # this is ugly ugly
groupby(template, '<>'.count)    # not obvious, but looks sweet
```

---

#### Update

To handle cases like: `foo<bar<int>>()`, you'll need a better `groupby` key function. To be specific, a key function that return the current depth-level for a given charachter.

Like this one:

```
def get_level(ch, level=[0]):
    current = level[0]
    if ch == '<':
        level[0] += 1
    if ch == '>':
        level[0] -= 1
        current = level[0]

    return current
```

That take advantage of the mutable argument `level` to perform some kind of memoization.

Observe that `remove_arguments` will now be more simple:

```
def remove_arguments(template, depth):
    res = []
    for k,g in groupby(template, get_level):
        if k < depth:
            res.append(''.join(g))
    return ''.join(res)
```

Comment: You don't need a list in the lambda - `x in '<>'` does the same.

Comment: `Template` is actually a class from `string`, we both got that wrong. :)

Comment: What about something like `foo<bar<int>>`? Its legal in the new standard (and likely to get used inadvertently regardless)

Comment: @WinstonEwert: Thanks for noticing that. I didn't thought/known of that case, it requires a better `groupby` key function to handle it. I've updated my answer :)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your code doesn't seem to work: `removeTemplateArguments("foo< bar<int> >()", 2)` has a trailing ">" that shouldn't be here according to your docstring:

- `foo< bar<> >()` (expected)
- `foo< bar<> >>()` (actual)

You nearly have written a [doctest](http://docs.python.org/library/doctest.html), finishing the work would have helped you catch the bug. Seems not that easy to fix by the way.

Next, I would avoid using names like `str` which shadows the [standard `str()` function](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#str).

My solution relies on *greedy* regular expressions and recursion (which seems natural here, given the nested template arguments).

```
import re

def removeTemplateArguments(function_name, depth):
    to_match = "(?P<class>\w+)<\s*(?P<nested>.*)\s*>(?P<paren>\(?\)?)"
    parts = re.match(to_match, function_name).groupdict()
    nested = '' if depthToRemove == 1
      else removeTemplateArguments(parts['nested'], depth-1)

    return "%s<%s>%s" % (parts['class'], nested, parts['paren'])
```

Not sure how pythonic it is. I do not add any spaces since between chevrons. I could add some logic to add them if needed. I'm using named subgroups to make my regular expression more easy to read.